# ol.interaction.DragBox - aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to be able to select a rectangular area of the map, but the selection must have a fixed aspect ratio. Let's assume 2:1 like this:
[image: aspect ration of 2:1]

I haven't found any `ol.interaction.DragBox` option to do this. Currently my only idea is to modify `ol.geom.Geometry` on `boxend` event:

```
interaction.on('boxend', function (evt) {
  var geom = evt.target.getGeometry(); 
  //TODO: shorten one side of geom to the specified aspect ratio
  var feat = new ol.Feature({
      geometry: geom
  });
  source.addFeature(feat);
});
```

Are there any other options? ([Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzymek/5n3uhz39/) to play around)